# WooCommerce Get Product Id Inside woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees Filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am unable to get the product id inside the woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees filter I'm assuming the syntax that I'm using is wrong as I can see the product id when I var_dump() the whole cart object.

Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_administration_fees', 10, 1 );

function add_administration_fees( $cart ) {
    // var_dump($cart);

    foreach ($cart as $item) {
        echo $item['product_id'];
    }
}
```

If I could also do it without the foreach loop that would be great as I'm going to make it so you can only have a single product in the cart at one time. This product is also a subscription type product using the WooCommerce Subscription plugin in case this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the cart contents (items) from the `$cart` object for which you can use the WooCommerce getter function `get_cart_contentents()`. So your code would look like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_administration_fees', 10, 1 );
function add_administration_fees( $cart ) {
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart_contents() as $item ) {
        echo $item['product_id'];
    }
}
```